# Configuring jmxAgent in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, jmx

To monitor and manage routes, we are trying to use JMX with camel. 
Our jmxAgent configuration is as follows.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <jmxAgent id="agent"
              connectorPort="9999"
              createConnector="false"
              usePlatformMBeanServer="true"
              serviceUrlPath="/jmxrmi/camel"
              loadStatisticsEnabled="true"
              statisticsLevel="All"/>

    <route>
```

A simple java class is used to connect to the "jmxAgent"

```
        try{
            JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://localhost:9999/jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi/camel");
            JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);

            MBeanServerConnection server = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I'm getting the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.acme.jmx.bridgeJMXBridge.main(JMXBridge.java:19)
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
```

Please give me some pointers to solve this issue.

Thanks,
San

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set

```
createConnector="true"
```

And when you do that, then Camel should log at INFO level the service url you can use from java code or jconsole to connect to it.